# How to replace <a> text

Tags: jquery, text, replace

I want to replace the text( "My Text" ) that is inside of a tag `<a>`
this is my code:

```
<a id="myID" href="#">
    My Text
    <img src="/layout/images/blank.gif">
</a>
```

I tried:

```
$( "#myID" ).text( "New Text" );
```

But I returns this error:

TypeError: string is not a function
message: "string is not a function"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
**proto**: Error

and:

```
$( "#myID" ).html( "New Text" );
```

TypeError: undefined is not a function
message: "undefined is not a function"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
**proto**: Error

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6o8ck0bo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** with callback function

```js
$("#myID").html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace("My Text", "New Text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="myID" href="#">
    My Text
    <img src="/layout/images/blank.gif">
</a>
```